# import file content to textarea

Tags: java, file-io, text-files, file-handling

```
try {
    int j=0;
    FileInputStream f1=new FileInputStream("E:\\fall 2018\\COMP 155\\IO\\jashandeep.txt");
    FileInputStream f2=new FileInputStream("E:\\fall 2018\\COMP 155\\IO\\jaimeet.txt");
    SequenceInputStream sr2=new SequenceInputStream(f1,f2);

    while((j=sr2.read())!=-1)
    {
        a1.setText(String.valueOf((char)j));
    }
    f1.close();
    f2.close();
    sr2.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

I am not able to get text inside textarea....help please!!

Comment: *I am not able to get text inside textarea* what text area? this code is writing (I assume) to a `a1` object (is this the textarea?). What exactly is the problem and where is it?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting one character on every iteration. You should append characters into existing value or set text once at all.

```
a1.append(String.valueOf((char)j));
```

Here is an example for one file:

```
a1.setText(String.valueOf(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.txt")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SequenceInputStream sr2=new SequenceInputStream(f1,f2);
while((j=sr2.read())!=-1)
{
    a1.setText(String.valueOf((char)j));
}
```

Assuming `a1` is a `JTextArea`, it would be easier to..

```
SequenceInputStream sr2=new SequenceInputStream(f1,f2);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sr2);
a1.read(irs, "Combined Files");
```